# Trouble in Nintegrate of double exponential related function

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

Pls. suggest how to plot given integral points.
 I am try with given below code:

```
                w = .0002; k = Pi/w;Eta=.001;gamma=.070;B=.002;
                \[Eta] = 1*10^-3; bk = Cosh[k*h0]^2/Sinh[2*k*h0]; tg = (
                2*Pi*Eta*bk)/(gamma*k^2);

                 cdg[t_?NumericQ] := 
                20*Quiet[NIntegrate[
              Exp[-(x^2)/8]*(1/(1 + B/x^2))*(1 - Exp[-t/tg*x^4*(1 +B/x^2)])/
              x, {x, 0, \[Infinity]}, AccuracyGoal -> 5]]
            Plot[Evaluate@Table[cdg[t,h0],{h0,.0001,.0005,.0001}],{t,0,0.1}]
```

Comment: You try  numerical solution NIntegrate[] but several parameters are not defined!

Comment: (1) Use `Plot`, `ListPlot`, or `Graphics`. (2) You mention "given integral points", but none are given. (3) If you tried something, please show it, indicate any errors, and describe the desired output.

Comment: You define `bk` but then use `Bk` in the definition of `tg`. Symbols are case senstive. 'h0' is not defined and you use the symbol `gamma` rather than the `gamma=0.07` that you have defined.

Comment: Thanhs@ Jack, I have correted the tpyo.

Comment: you have defined `cdg` to accept one argument, then give it two in`Plot`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The biggest issue is that you define `cdg` with one argument  (`t`) and then call it with two arguments (`t` and `h0`).

```
w = .0002 // Rationalize; 
k = Pi/w; 
Eta = .001 // Rationalize; 
gamma = .070 // Rationalize; 
B = .002 // Rationalize;
η = 1*10^-3; 
bk[h0_] := Cosh[k*h0]^2/Sinh[2*k*h0]; 
tg[h0_] := (2*Pi*Eta*bk[h0])/(gamma*k^2);

cdg[t_?NumericQ, h0_?NumericQ] :=
 20*NIntegrate[
   Exp[-(x^2)/8]*(1/(1 + B/x^2))*(1 - Exp[-t/tg[h0]*x^4*(1 + B/x^2)])/x, {x, 0, ∞},
   AccuracyGoal -> 7]

Plot[Evaluate@
  Table[cdg[t, h0], {h0, 1*^-4, 5*^-4, 1*^-4}],
 {t, 0, 1/10},
 PlotPoints -> 50,
 PlotLegends -> Placed["Expressions", {.75, .4}],
 ImageSize -> Large]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Due to all of the overlap, it is easier to see in separate plots

```
Table[
  Plot[
   cdg[t, h0],
   {t, 0, 1/10},
   PlotPoints -> 50,
   PlotLabel -> StringForm["h0 = ``", h0],
   ImageSize -> Medium],
  {h0, 1*^-4, 5*^-4, 1*^-4}] // Column
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks@Hanlon. Can u suggest  the role of "rationalize" command.

Comment: To reduce precision issues in numeric calculations I prefer to use exact numbers for known values.

Answer (score 1):

the simplest approach here is to make everything that depends on `h0` be explicitly a function of `h0`.

This works.

```
w = .0002; k = Pi/w;
Eta = .001; gamma = .070;
B = .002;
\[Eta] = 1*10^-3;
bk[h0_] = Cosh[k*h0]^2/Sinh[2*k*h0];
tg[h0_] = (2*Pi*Eta*bk[h0])/(gamma*k^2);
cdg[t_?NumericQ, h0_] := 
 20*Quiet[NIntegrate[
    Exp[-(x^2)/
       8]*(1/(1 + B/x^2))*(1 - Exp[-t/tg[h0]*x^4*(1 + B/x^2)])/x, {x, 
     0, \[Infinity]}, AccuracyGoal -> 5]]
Plot[Evaluate@Table[cdg[t, h0], {h0, .0001, .0005, .0001}], {t, 0, 
  0.1}]
```